# Ending explanation for the last episode of "Wet Hot American Summer: First Day of Summer Camp"

Tags: plot-explanation, wet-hot-american-summer

In the final episode of Wet Hot American Summer: First Day of Summer Camp,

> Eric (played by Chris Pine) is shot and then run over by a Jeep.

But he appears a week later hitching a ride to New York. There is no explanation of how he survived.

Granted there are many improbable scenarios in the series. Is there a plausible explanation for this?

**edit**

Ok, I'm after an explanation that can be cited. I realise that pretty much every thing in the TV series is implausible.

Comment: Possibly we should change the tag to suggest it's regarding the TV series, not [the movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0243655/), but 'wet-hot-american-summer-tv' is too long...

Comment: @Tautologist sure, I was wondering how to alter the title itself also as it is in itself a spoiler, was thinking 'ending explanation'

Comment: Good point as we shouldn't have spoilers in titles. In my opinion 'ending explanation' is fine.

Comment: There is a plausible explanation. He's a ghost.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a satire on how in the entertainment industry someone can be shot, fall off the ridge of a roof on a 2-3 story building, get ran over by a car, and in the end magically show up as if it never happened. I think this is the most sensible reason that a show full of satire aimed at  the implausible in the entertainment industry would add such an implausible plot point as a finale. I think maybe even the point might've been to end it on the most implausible plot point of all.

Additionally, Eric showcased some musical magic powers in one of his scenes, I guess you might be able to attribute it to that if you prefer but my bet is on the former.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no plausible explanation. That's part of the charm of the series. It's full of implausible scenarios. For example, talking vegetable cans.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for something that fills the time gap between that evening and a week later which would explain how he survived

Answer (score 1):

I believe the guy nicknamed 'The Falcon' saved Eric, because of the Falcon screeching in the final scene. Maybe they added that just to avoid people feeling bad over Eric dying.

Comment: Will have to re-watch the ending again but you maybe onto something

Answer (score 1):

I have two possible (ridiculous) scenarios for the equally insane ending.

1. He was faking his death from the get go. The 'soldier' who shot him had a sniper rifle in the middle of a bunch of infantry, shot and then immediately ducked his head and walked out. He was also blond, so it could have been that theater troop guy who played the warden in the play. Then maybe he did some sleight of hand or something and dropped somebody elses body off the roof to get run over by trucks.
2. The bird that flew by at the end was a Crow. He was the Crow all along! You know that magically returned from the grave movie character.